# Foreach with bootstrap and images to list 6 column items

Tags: c#, html, css, razor, bootstrap-4

I using a foreach to list a clients with images, it should be list with 6 columns.
For example I have 18 client`s and it should be like list with 6 columns and 3 rows.

There the razor code and html:

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var patient in Model)
{
    <div class="col-xs-2">

        <figure style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10%; display: block;">

            <img src="~/Content/images/pdficon.png" alt="">

            <figcaption>
                <div style="margin-top: 5%"><h4>@(patient.Name)</h4></div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
}
```

The current result is:

[My sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROtKG.png)

There is 6 columns it`s okey, but row location is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to use a break after 6 patients.

```
@{int patientCnt = 0};
@foreach (var patient in Model)
{
    <div class="col-xs-2">

        <figure style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10%; display: block;">

            <img src="~/Content/images/pdficon.png" alt="">

            <figcaption>
                <div style="margin-top: 5%"><h4>@(patient.Name)</h4></div>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
@{if(patientCnt%6==0)
       @Html.Raw("<br/>");
patientCnt++;
}

}
```